# amazon_es amazones - Failed to install template: Failed to parse mapping [_default_]

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, aws-elasticsearch

I am using `amazon_es` plugin on my `logstash`.

My logstash.conf looks like following:

```
input {
    tcp {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 5959
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["XXXXXXX.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        region => "ap-south-1"
        aws_access_key_id => "XXXXXXXXX"
        aws_secret_access_key => "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        index => "production-logs-%(YYYY-MM-dd)"
    }
}
```

I have following error:

```
[ERROR] 2018-04-17 12:03:59.056 [[main]-pipeline-manager] amazones - Failed to install template: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [@version]"}},"status":400}
```

Comment: It look like you have a string in your field `@version`, perhaps try without the json codec.